# How do I use Vector.map() in Actionscript (to map to elements of a different type)?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, functional-programming

Actionscript's `Vector` class has a [`map()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#map%28%29) function which, as you'd expect, allows you to map elements from one Vector into a new Vector.

However, as far as I can tell, **these elements need to be the same type as the original Vector, which makes `map()` basically useless.**

The typical use-case of a `map()` function is to map elements their properties or to a string.  However, this code:

```
logHistory.map( function(log:LogRecord, i, a):String
    { return log.timeStamp + ": " + log.value.toString(); } );
```

is giving me this error at runtime:

```
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "123: xyz" to com.mycompany.LogRecord.
```

I cannot find a single reference of using `map()` to map to elements of a different type.  Can you *really* not do that in Actionscript!?

Comment: From the livedocs (altough i'm sure you've checked them out already): "The result Vector has the same base type and length as the original Vector." Of course you can achieve what you want to do...just not with map...so i guess you're right and it is useless, hah

Comment: The base type cannot change but the element types can be subclasses.